# How to turn on assembly binding logging in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I ran into this error and couldn't figure what's missing:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxx, Version=1.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5067b3d1110b13c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"xxxxx, Version=1.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5067b3d1110b13c"}
```

In the detailed exception window, it also tells me:

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

However, I couldn't make it work. I found another post about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net). I tried those entries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
Add:
DWORD ForceLog set value to 1
DWORD LogFailures set value to 1
DWORD LogResourceBinds set value to 1
String LogPath set value to folder for logs ie) C:\FusionLog\
```

But it still doesn't work. Actually, I also set EnableLog to 1.

What did I do wrong? Can somebody please help. I'm using C# express 2010 in WinXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/141281/WRN-Asssembly-binding-logging-is-turned-OFF

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\FUSLOGVW.exe` to see if you have logs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I didn't find FusLogVw.exe in ...\v7.0A\... folder, bug I did find one in ...\v6.0A\...folder. However, this log viewer doesn't show me any failures, even though my C# express reports in its exception window. If I change the setting to log all binds to disk, I could see about 20 assembly loaded, and all say 'the operation was successful'. In C# exception window, it still tells me 'Assembly binding loggins is turned off'. Do I have to get one in ...\v7.0A\... folder because I'm using C# express 2010?

Comment: I'm not rightly sure, since I'm not clear how Fusion treats v2.0 and v4.0 assemblies differently (if at all). One idea is to install the Win7 SDK and try to run Fuslogvw.exe from there, since it could be runtime-dependent. This is all just speculation, however. It is odd that you are getting 2 different results...